# Bounds on $ \sum_{i=1}^m\left\{\frac{1}{p_i}\prod_{j=i+1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)\right\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products, infinite-product

I am interested in the following sum

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^m\left\{\frac{1}{p_i}\prod_{j=i+1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)\right\},
\end{equation}
where $p_i$ is the i'th prime number.

I assume that finding a closed form expression for any $m$ is very difficult, so I am interested in approximations or upper and lower bounds on these sums. I do think this sum converges for $m\rightarrow\infty$ but I am not sure.

An obvious upper bound is just $\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{p_i}$, but it is definitely not a good one.

Since the factors in the product can be lower bounded by $(1-\frac{1}{j})$, the sum can be lower bounded by $\sum\frac{1}{p_i}\frac{i}{m}$. But this is also not a good lower bound.

edit: I forgot to mention that $p_i$ represents the i'th prime number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously,$$\frac{1}{p_i}\prod_{j=i+1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)=\prod_{j=i+1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)-\prod_{j=i}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right),$$
because $$\prod_{j=i}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\,\prod_{j=i+1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right),$$ so the telescoping sum will be
$$\sum_{i=1}^m\left\{\frac{1}{p_i}\prod_{j=i+1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right)\right\}=1-\prod_{j=1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{p_j}\right).$$

Comment: The first equality isn't entirely clear to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @PhPanda See if you understand this: $x_3x_4x_5\cdots - x_2x_3x_4\cdots = (1 - x_2)x_3x_4x_5\cdots$, then here $1 - x_2 = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{p_i}\right) = \frac{1}{p_i}$ so we can factor it out.

Comment: An interesting alternative form of the answer is $1 - \frac{\phi(P_m)}{P_m}$, where $P_m = \prod_{i=1}^m p_i$ is the $m$-th primorial number. It might be interesting that such primorial numbers satisfy $\frac{\phi(P)}{P} < \frac{\phi(n)}{n}$ for any other $n < P$ i.e. it is the "current minimum".